# How to dealloc a singleton?

Tags: iphone, ios, singleton, dealloc

I have a class named 'Capture' that is a subclass of NSObject and it also adds views to a superview.

I have added a Settings.bundle which consists of slider. When the slider value is 'ON/1' I show the views in 'Capture' in the main window as subview. When the slider value is 'OFF/0' I have to remove the view added from 'Capture' and release all the objects present in 'Capture'.

I simply don't want to hide the views created by 'Capture' class on to the main view, when the slider value is 'OFF/0'.

I want to dealloc the 'Capture' when the app in sent to background and not when the app terminates, so i cannot use the notification UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification to dealloc a singleton.

If i just hide the views displayed by 'Capture', there will be unnecessary use of memory for the 'Capture' class

So now how do i dealloc a singleton.

'Capture' class views will be on top of every view controller, even when the events occurs.
It is allocated once by class method called in AppDelegate.

singleton is created this way:

```
static ScreenCapture *sharedScreen = nil;

+(Capture *)sharedScreenCapture
{
    if (!sharedScreen) 
    {
        sharedScreen = [[Capture alloc] init];
    }
    return sharedScreen;
}
```

Comment: Show the code for how you are creating the singleton.

Comment: The curse of making everything a singleton ;-)

Comment: static ScreenCapture *sharedScreen = nil;                           +(Capture *)sharedCapture
{
    if (!sharedScreen) 
    {
  sharedScreen = [[Capture alloc] init];
 }
 return sharedScreen;
}                                                                          This method is called in appdelegate.

Comment: Is there really any need to release the singleton ? I don't think so.  Because if you release it somewhere it will lose its value which is not the behavior of `singleton`.

Comment: End the application.  If you didn't want the object to persist for the life of the app you shouldn't have made it a singleton.

Comment: "It is allocated once by class method called in AppDelegate."  So, any reason it's not just a property of AppDelegate?

Answer (score 3):

Why not to create some `ReLoad` method which will clear all your cashes and nullify your private variable?

Something like this:

```
+(void) reLoad {
    @synchronized(self) {
        // clear all the cashes...
        sharedScreen = nil;
    }
}
```

and to call it after receiving `UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification`

`[ScreenCapture reLoad];`

Comment: But when the user sends this app in background and changes the slider value for this app and the comes back to the app, the change should be visible. foe example, if the user changes the slider value to 'NO' the view displayed by 'Capture' shouldn't be visible. Since it wont be visible I just thought of deallocating 'Capture'.

Answer (score 2):

You can add another method:

```
+ (void)destroyScreenCapture
{
    sharedScreen = nil;
}
```

Consider whether singleton is actually the correct pattern for you to use and if you really need to destroy the singleton or whether you should just 'clean' it to release all of the memory for the data that it isn't currently using.

Comment: thanks ..I was of the notion that a singleton is not supposed be deallocated, and if deallocated , it shouldn't be done directly..

Comment: A singleton shouldn't be deallocated, if you need to it suggests that it shouldn't be a singleton.